# Android Studio Emulator process for Pixel_6_API_30 has terminated error

Tags: android-emulator

I have a student with a Windows 11 laptop that we can't get the emulator to work. We get the error: **emulator process for Pixel_6_API_30 has terminated**.

We have tried the many suggestions we have found Googling the error. We have uninstalled and reinstall Android Studio Electric Eel, even tried installing an older version of Studio and same error. Here is the portion of the log file with the emulator from the fresh install.  Hoping someone can points us in the right direction.

2023-01-19 17:40:07,442 [ 712111]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jbr
2023-01-19 17:40:07,562 [ 712231]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - C:\Users\Aariyah Pech.android\avd\Pixel_6_API_30.avd\hardware-qemu.ini.lock\pid not found for Pixel_6_API_30
2023-01-19 17:40:07,563 [ 712232]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - C:\Users\Aariyah Pech.android\avd\Pixel_6_API_30.avd\userdata-qemu.img.lock\pid not found for Pixel_6_API_30
2023-01-19 17:40:07,570 [ 712239]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_6_API_30 is online, assuming it's not
2023-01-19 17:40:13,971 [ 718640]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - "C:\Users\Aariyah Pech\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe" -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_6_API_30 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
2023-01-19 17:40:14,105 [ 718774]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Android emulator version 31.3.14.0 (build_id 9322596) (CL:N/A)
2023-01-19 17:40:14,106 [ 718775]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - emulator: INFO: Found systemPath C:\Users\Aariyah Pech\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86
2023-01-19 17:40:14,121 [ 718790]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - emulator: INFO: Found systemPath C:\Users\Aariyah Pech\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86
2023-01-19 17:40:16,754 [ 721423]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
2023-01-19 17:40:16,829 [ 721498]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\Aariyah Pech.android\avd\Pixel_6_API_30.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2023-01-19 17:40:20,352 [ 725021]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
2023-01-19 17:40:20,352 [ 725021]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - IPv4 server found: 192.168.1.1
2023-01-19 17:40:20,352 [ 725021]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - IPv6 DNS server found: 2600:6c46:4500:d82::1
2023-01-19 17:40:20,352 [ 725021]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - added library vulkan-1.dll
2023-01-19 17:40:20,352 [ 725021]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
2023-01-19 17:40:20,352 [ 725021]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
2023-01-19 17:40:20,644 [ 725313]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.d.v.VirtualDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 connected
2023-01-19 17:40:20,666 [ 725335]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - *** Basic token auth will be deprecated soon, please migrate to using -grpc-use-jwt ***
2023-01-19 17:40:20,675 [ 725344]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: +token
2023-01-19 17:40:20,675 [ 725344]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Advertising in: C:\Users\Aariyah Pech\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_11632.ini
2023-01-19 17:40:20,790 [ 725459]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to sync vcpu reg
2023-01-19 17:40:20,836 [ 725505]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to sync vcpu reg
2023-01-19 17:40:20,837 [ 725506]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to sync vcpu reg
2023-01-19 17:40:20,837 [ 725506]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to sync vcpu reg
2023-01-19 17:40:20,837 [ 725506]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to sync vcpu reg
2023-01-19 17:40:20,837 [ 725506]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - setDisplayConfigs w 1080 h 2400 dpiX 420 dpiY 420
2023-01-19 17:40:20,903 [ 725572]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to sync vcpu reg
2023-01-19 17:40:20,903 [ 725572]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to sync vcpu reg
2023-01-19 17:40:20,903 [ 725572]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to sync vcpu reg
2023-01-19 17:40:20,903 [ 725572]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to sync vcpu reg
2023-01-19 17:40:20,918 [ 725587]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\Aariyah Pech.android\emu-update-last-check.ini for reading.
2023-01-19 17:40:21,145 [ 725814]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to sync vcpu reg
2023-01-19 17:40:21,145 [ 725814]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to sync vcpu reg
2023-01-19 17:40:21,146 [ 725815]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to sync vcpu reg
2023-01-19 17:40:21,146 [ 725815]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to sync vcpu reg
2023-01-19 17:40:21,146 [ 725815]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to sync vcpu reg
2023-01-19 17:40:21,146 [ 725815]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to sync vcpu reg
2023-01-19 17:40:21,146 [ 725815]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - VCPU shutdown request
2023-01-19 17:40:21,147 [ 725816]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - VCPU shutdown request
2023-01-19 17:40:21,147 [ 725816]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - VCPU shutdown request
2023-01-19 17:40:21,386 [ 726055]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:
2023-01-19 17:40:21,386 [ 726055]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\Aariyah Pech.android\emu-update-last-check.ini for reading.
2023-01-19 17:40:21,387 [ 726056]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - - Start Android Studio
2023-01-19 17:40:21,388 [ 726057]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - - Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
2023-01-19 17:40:21,388 [ 726057]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - - Click "SDK Tools" tab
2023-01-19 17:40:21,388 [ 726057]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - - Check "Android Emulator" checkbox
2023-01-19 17:40:21,388 [ 726057]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - - Click "OK"
2023-01-19 17:40:21,388 [ 726057]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 -
2023-01-19 17:40:23,327 [ 727996]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.e.EmulatorController - Unable to connect Pixel 6 API 30 (5554)
2023-01-19 17:40:25,508 [ 730177]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 30 - Process finished with exit code 0
2023-01-19 17:40:25,670 [ 730339]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.d.v.VirtualDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 disconnected
2023-01-19 17:40:25,674 [ 730343]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.a.p.ProcessNameMonitor - Removing emulator-5554: 2103920473
2023-01-19 17:40:26,175 [ 730844]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - C:\Users\Aariyah Pech.android\avd\Pixel_6_API_30.avd\hardware-qemu.ini.lock\pid not found for Pixel_6_API_30
2023-01-19 17:40:26,175 [ 730844]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - C:\Users\Aariyah Pech.android\avd\Pixel_6_API_30.avd\userdata-qemu.img.lock\pid not found for Pixel_6_API_30
2023-01-19 17:40:26,176 [ 730845]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_6_API_30 is online, assuming it's not
2023-01-19 17:40:42,927 [ 747596]   INFO - #c.i.i.a.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1